# Aplicación no reconoce los permisos FINE_LOCATION

Tags: android, react-native

En mi aplicación estoy recibiendo el siguiente error 'Looks like the app doesn't have  the permissions to access location', pero no sé por qué está sucediendo esto. Algunos días antes funcionaba bien, pero después de agregar Notificaciones de permisos, no probé estos permisos y las notificaciones funcionaron bien, pero traté de usar un Mapa (con estos permisos) y mostrar este error. Este es mi Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission
    android:name="com.sapco.sapcoapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sapco.sapcoapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="XXXXXXXXXXX" />
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="XXXXXXX" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.XXX.XXX" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
    <service
        android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Comment: Por favor traduce la parte inicial de la pregunta, este es el sitio en español.

Comment: Perfecto, ya lo hice, perdón por eso, se me había ido así. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando la `API 21` o superior (por lo que veo utilizas la `API 22)` deberás añadir esto también:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo agregué y me sigue diciendo lo mismo, pues el mismo error, y la verdad no tengo idea de qué sea.